# Trigger the AutoComplete drop down to show on click

Tags: vb.net, autocomplete, textbox

I am using the TextBox `AutoComplete` feature. The results I am returning only start with the letter "D" and the users might not know that... So entering anything other than a word starting with the letter "D" won't display the drop down suggestion box.

Is there any way I can trigger it to show the drop down suggestion box when I click on the TextBox without any text entered so they can at least see the options which are available to them? I am hoping I don't have to come up with another solution which will of course take hours of work.

Comment: What have you got so far? (code)

Comment: I do not believe what you want is possible with built-in functionality.  As an alternative, consider setting a cue banner (a.k.a. watermark) on the Textbox to inform the user that the word should start with a "D".   [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545181/em-setcuebanner-sendmessage-vb-net-usercontrol-not-working)

Comment: Hmm If you don't want to spend sometime to find a better solution, then just `If YourTextBox.TextLength = 0 Then SendKeys.Send("d")` in the `Click` event.

Comment: Thanks JQSOFT. That actually worked pretty well thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3185587/how-to-make-autocomplete-on-a-textbox-show-suggestions-when-empty , there is another solution posted there.